# Cannot apply the customer JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a class which extends JPanel, but it is not working. Would someone tell me how can I solve the issue. It looks like the error is on "super";

This is my class:

```
public class DivCommentJPane extends JPanel  {

private BeanPanel thisBean;
private CommentItem thisComment; 
private String pageErrorPrefix="Error On DivCommentJPane.java : "; 
private PDFNotesBean bean;


public DivCommentJPane(CommentItem comment ){
    //thisBean=bean;
    super();
    thisComment=comment;
    setting();



}
```

The code below is to add DivCommentJPane into another JPane:

```
ArrayList<CommentItem>sortComment= lstComment;
         Collections.sort(sortComment,CommentItem.sortPage);
         for(CommentItem comm: sortComment){
             DivCommentJPane d=new DivCommentJPane(comm);
             listCommentPane.add(d, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         }
```

Comment: `super()` must be the first call in a constructor. In your case it could be omitted completely, since it is called by default (the constructor with no arguments).

Comment: _"it is not working."_, without more context, is **never** a valid explanation for what your problem is. It looks like @vandale (+1) caught your problem, but please make an effort next time to better explain your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), "[e]ach region may contain no more than one component."

Therefore repeated attempts to add to the `CENTER` region (`listCommentPane.add(d, BorderLayout.CENTER);` ) will end up replacing what was previously there.

You will have to use a different layout manage instead.